# Terminology: "local minimum" vs. "non-global minimum"

Tags: optimization, soft-question

In engineering literature, I often read statements along the lines of:

> We observe poor performance whenever our algorithm converges to a **local minimum** of the cost function.

Now I have to formulate such a statement myself, and I have trouble using the term "local minimum" in that context because a global minimum is also a local minimum, thus rendering the above statement complete nonsense.

In my opinion, the best way would be

> We observe poor performance whenever our algorithm converges to a **non-global minimum** of the cost function.

BUT the term "non-global minimum" is more than a hundred times more uncommon than "local minimum" according to Google search, so I feel like I am off track here. What do you think is the best possible formulation?

Comment: *non-global* is implied, I don't think that the expression *local* is problematic. *a local minimum* is used by contrast with *the minimum*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. I agree that it would hardly ever cause confusion, but after all we are talking math here.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are right, but I think you want to see a problem where there is none.

Comment: A local minimum can of course also be a global minimum (at least one of them would have to be), but then in all cases i have seen in literature, that is always pointed out explicitly, so if global is not mentioned, it is assumed it is not the case.

Comment: The phrase "non-global minimum" is extremely awkward, but if you want to be pedantic I suggest "...whenever our algorithm converges to a local minimum *which is not the global minimum* of the cost function" (emphasis only for highlighting and should be omitted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right; in this context what is meant is specifically a local minimum which is not the global minimum, and a good shorter way to refer to that is "non-global minimum".

I don't think it should worry you that this phrase is much less common than "local minimum", since in most other contexts "local minimum", i.e. something which might be the global minimum but also might not, is what is meant. You're using a more unusual term because you are expressing a more unusual concept, that is all.